# Starting a netty application on a linux server

Tags: java, linux, netty, background-process

I have written a little netty server application, packed in a jar file that I want to deploy on a linux server.

Since I have no professional experience with deploying java applications, I was wondering if it is enough to start the netty server by doing:

```
java -jar NettyServer.jar  NettyServer &
```

Obviously a script could be created to ensure the correct user starts the process etc., but is this the way (stand-alone) java services is being deployed?

It seems almost too easy, considering every other question/answer seems to mention some big hunky container-bean-glassfish-tomcat-whatnot (which I might consider later on if/when issues arise)

Comment: You might want to check out something like `supervisor` or `god` so that you can run it as a Linux service at startup etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes thats the way - no container needed!! I built a middleware (http://sourceforge.net/projects/serviceconnecto/) using netty as underlaying framework. It's the way i start my server as well! Just verify the classpath is set correctly - meaning libraries are in correct place and the jar archive is correctly built.

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer Upstart to start services on linux. http://upstart.ubuntu.com/
It is very easy to use, and can also restart your application on crash.
I hope it helps.